# MVC routing only applying to certain action results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Do I have to route a special route for every action result in a controller, or do you do one route, and have to live by that standard thought the controller? I thought you could make a default route, and then a special route for any instance you wanted. I keep running into a problem where one of my routes will hit my action Results correctly, but then the others no longer work. This code is probably the wrong way, but hence why I am posting it here. PLease try to clarify this for me if you can. I understand that I am suppose to be able to do {controller}/{action}/{id} for example. So that should hit Settings/GetSite/{siteid} for the following

```
 public ActionResult GetSite(int id);
```

Routes configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "SettingsUpdateEnviorment",
            "{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Settings", action = "UpdateProperties" },
            new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
        );



        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "ProfileRoute",
           url: "Profiles/{userId}",
           defaults: new
           {
               controller = "Profile",
               action = "Index",
           }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Settings",                                           // Route name
            "Settings/{id}",                            // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Settings", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult GetSite(int enviornmentID, string name)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddSite(int id)
    {           
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = id });
    }
```

So, the URL works as expected for Settings/1 to hit the Index actionresult Index(int id). Then, when I try to do the ActionResult for GetSite(int enviornmentID, string name) using the following actionLink:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(site.Name, "GetSite", "Settings", new { enviornmentID = Model.Enviorment.EnvironmentID, name = site.Name }, null)
```

It creates the URL correctly as follows: Settings/GetSite?enviornmentID=1&name=CaseyTesting2, but gives me an error stating that I am trying to send a null value to my Index(int id) actionResult. I thought that since I am using the action name and it's same params, that MVC will figure the route out? Why is this not functioning for me, or what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: I apologize ahead of time for this being my fourth question regarding routes [normally I catch on immediately], along the same ideals. I am for what ever reason having a real issue with this routing stuff. I understand how the default is suppose to work, but when trying to make custom ones, I get all messed up. :(

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I was doing thanks to this article http://www.itworld.com/development/379646/aspnet-mvc-5-brings-attribute-based-routing. I was mixing up the order, when I had everything else correct. Then I was missing the param names being identical, when everything else was correct. So I kept having minor issues when trying to find the problem out. I also switched to MVC5's attribute routing, and like it much more.

So this is my code that is now working:

RoutConfig

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();



        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "ProfileRoute",
           url: "Profiles/{userId}",
           defaults: new
           {
               controller = "Profile",
               action = "Index",
           }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The controller code

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("settings")]
[Route("{action=index}")]
public class SettingsController : ZenController
{       
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {


        return View(model);
    }

    [Route("GetSite/{sitename:alpha}")]
    public ActionResult GetSite(string sitename)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Thanks again everyone! Happy coding!